# Setting up Volttron Central (VC)

Tags: volttron

I have some questions about Volttron Central (VC):

1. What library/module/webserver is used to serve web content (html,
   css, js, etc.)?
2. What is default username/password? And how do I
   change it? I could not find this info in the doc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC uses a gevent based web server.  We have added some custom functionality to it for registering routes etc.

The default username/password fro the admin interface is admin/admin.  Soon this will available through the volttron-cfg interface.  To change the username/password this requires you to modify the configuration file for the agent.

To create a password for use with VC you can execute

```
#Authentication for users is handled through a naive password algorithm
import hashlib
hashlib.sha512(password).hexdigest() where password is the plain text password.
```

This configuration is how the username/password/groups are created.  Everything other than the users node is deprecated in this configuration file however.
https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/develop/services/core/VolttronCentral/config